# How to query a named graph in Apache Jena Fuseki server

Tags: sparql, fuseki, apache-jena, named-graphs

I am laoding a .ttl file into the Jena Fuseki server and instead of the default graph I am using the named graph `<http://examples/test>`.

```
/home/user/jena-fuseki-1.1.1/./s-put http://192.168.1.38:3030/ds/data http://example/test /home/user/testdata.ttl
```

I am able to load the graph and retrieve result using the following command.

```
/home/user/jena-fuseki-1.1.1/./s-get http://192.168.1.38:3030/ds/data http://example/test
```

But when I start querying using the `s-query` command, it is taking the default unnamed graph. How to make the `s-query` command work on the named graph.

```
 /home/user/jena-fuseki-1.1.1/./s-query --service http://localhost:3030/ds/query 'SPARQL Query'
```

This is doing the query on the default unnamed graph. How to make it  work on the named graph `<http://example/test>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the named graph in a query, use the `GRAPH` keyword.

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
  GRAPH <http://examples/test>
  {
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
  }
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#queryDataset

Comment: You missed some brackets. Fuseki 2.3.0 returns an error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219499/how-to-unload-data-from-jena-fuseki-server how to unload a named graph from jena fuseki?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the named graph in the SPARQL query using a `FROM`-clause. For example to get all triples in your graph use

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
FROM <http://examples/test>
WHERE {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
```

A detailed description and further options can be found in the [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language specification of W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#specifyingDataset).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219499/how-to-unload-data-from-jena-fuseki-server how to unload from fuseki?