# How to unload data from Jena Fuseki server

Tags: fuseki, apache-jena

I am loading data to a named graph in fuseki server using the following command .
How to remove the particular graph from jena fuseki server.Is there any simple commands similarly.

```
 '/home/user/jena-fuseki-1.1.1/./s-put http://192.168.1.2:3030/ds/data http://graph/graph1  /home/user/files/uniquename.ttl'
```

How can i unload named graph from jena fuseki server.

Comment: @AndyS can u please help

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to do this in a similar manner to adding a graph
 `s-delete http://192.168.1.2:3030/ds/data http://graph/graph1`
[SPARQL Graph Store HTTP Protocol](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/#http-delete)